# Have a switch statement check multiple cases without fall-through

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is there a way to have a switch statement check and possibly execute each case individually?

```
switch (true) {
    case (condition1): // this could be true or not
      // Do thing 1...

    case (condition2): // this could be true or not
      // Do thing 2...

    default: // do this if all others are false
      // Do thing 3...
      break;
}
```

I want to be able to do thing 1, thing 2, both, or neither (default to thing 3).

Using break in each case doesn't work because it can't do thing 1 and thing 2. Fall-through doesn't work because it does all of them even if only one is true.

Is there a way for switch statements to do this? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You want an `if`/`else`, not a `switch`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#taking_advantage_of_fall-through

Comment: Try putting `condition1`, `condition2`, and so on, into an Array, then use [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`some`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`every`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: `switch (true)` is a code smell for me - I agree with a previous comment that `if/else` is better. However, if you really must use a `switch`, depending on the precise conditions, you might be able to achieve what you want by having a `break` at the end of the second case, but not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a series of `if` statements and call things.

```js
const
    f = (condition1, condition2) => {
        if (condition1) console.log('thing 1');
        if (condition1 || condition2) console.log('thing 2');
        else console.log('thing 3');
        console.log('---');
    };
    
f(false, false); // thing3
f(false, true ); // thing2
f(true,  false); // thing1 thing 2
f(true,  true ); // thing1 thing 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A not recommended use of `switch`. Just add a break in the last clause of the group.

If you like to have a more dynamic approach, you could add a `case` clause with a value not equal to the `switch` value, like `false`, [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) or [`Symbol()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

```
case new Symbol:
    break
```

The last two expressions are not equal to any other (not stored) value.

```js
const
    f = (condition1, condition2) => {
        switch (true) {
            case condition1:
                console.log('thing 1');

            case condition2:
                console.log('thing 2');
                break;                  // stops falling into default clause

            default:
                console.log('thing 3');
        }
        console.log('---');
    };
    
f(false, false); // thing3
f(false, true ); // thing2
f(true,  false); // thing1 thing 2
f(true,  true ); // thing1 thing 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```